# Finding area ratios in triangle cut by circle

Tags: integration, geometry, trigonometry, area

This is another one of those problems that was a brain teaser, and I am curious about how to do this in a more elegant way.

Given:

[image]

I want to find the ratio of the blue area to the red one. Initially I had thought the way to do it was use the equation of a circle $x^{2}+y^{2} = 16$ (since we know the radius) and see where it intersects the line $y=\frac{3}{4}x+3$ (I know I could place the point A at the origin too, but I thought dispensing with the coordinates of the center of the circle would be simpler). Anyhow, the idea I had was to subtract the area under the triangle from the circle first, and then do he same with the whole triangle by just subtracting integrals with the limits at the intersection points. So, for the blue area, I would first find where point D is:
$$x^2 +y^2 =16 \text{ and substituting } y = \frac{3}{4}x+3$$
$$(\frac{3}{4}x+3)^{2} + x^2 = 16 \rightarrow \frac{9}{16}x^{2}+\frac{9}{2}x+9+x^2=16$$
$$\frac{25}{16}x^{2} + \frac{9}{2}x +9 = 16 \rightarrow \frac{25}{16}x^{2} + \frac{9}{2}x -7 = 0$$
Which is a perfectly good quadratic and we can solve that and I get an intersection point of $(1.12,3.84)$.

Then I can integrate my circle within those limits, subtracting the triangle underneath (which would be described by the linear equation)

$$\int_{-4}^{1.12}(16-x^2)^{1/2}dx-\int_{-4}^{1.12}\frac{3}{4}x+3dx $$

That first integral is ugly, and I have to say I am not sure how to approach it because I don't know the angle to the point D to set the limits for the trig substitution that I ordinarily might try.

More to the point, what was bothering me was that there has to be a more elegant method for this. I suspect there is some geometric rule or procedure that I am missing here; I tried, for example, dropping a line segment OD which makes for an isosceles triangle AOD and then I could use the relevant formulas for the area of a circle segment. But here again I don't know the angle involved. I could certainly find the angles by, for example, making a line segment OD and knowing that the angle A is $\sin^{-1}(0.6)$ because the triangle is a 3-4-5. That angle would get me both angles AOD and COD, and I could use trig functions to derive the lengths of various triangle sides, which would enable me to find the areas I want. But there was something inelegant about these solutions as well, though if that's the way to do it then that's the way to do it.

In any case I am curious what other folks came up with.

Answer (score 1):

Area of the white region is $$\mathrm{area}(\triangle DOA)+\mathrm{area}(\mathrm{sector}\ DOA)$$

$$\mathrm{area}(\mathrm{sector}\ DOA)=\frac{\angle DOC}{2\pi}\pi(4^2)=\frac{2\angle DAC}{2\pi}\pi(4^2)=16\arctan(3/4)$$

Also if length of parpendicular from $D$ to $AC$ is $x$, then $\frac{x}{6}=\frac{|AD|}{|AB|}=\frac{|AD|}{10}$. $$\mathrm{area}(\triangle DOA)=\frac12x|OA|=\frac12\times\frac35|AD|\times4$$ So you just need to figure out the coordinates of $D$ and you have your area.

Comment: Thanks -- I suppose there no avoiding using trig functions, then! (Though I suspect that doing it in radians yields more elegant answers).

Comment: It also just dawned on me that I found the coordinates of D substituting in earlier, which yields the length of AD.